# Transfer file programatically between two Raspberry Pi 3 via bluetooth

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I want to transfer a csv file from one pi to another pi via bluetooth. I tried to using OBEX Server but It's not happening. Can you have any other way to do this?
I am working RPI 3 model B with raspbian os.

Comment: How about over the bluetooth serial port?

Comment: How to do this I am not aware about this. If you have some links then share it.

Comment: You can pair with the another pi, then write a small program (in C or Python), reading your csv file, then write to the bluetooth serial port `/dev/ttyAMA0`. On the another pi, read from the bluetooth serial port.

Comment: @Kong Chun Ho
I also write a program in python using lightblue libraries But it shows me this error: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module> obex.sendfile(device, channel, "/bluetooth/RSSI.csv") File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lightblue/_obex.py", line 257, in sendfile raise OBEXError("server denied the Put request")
OBEXError: server denied the Put request`.

Comment: Code for the program is here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/53863/5538

Comment: @Kong Chun Ho I also write a program in python using lightblue libraries But it shows me this error.
Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in obex.sendfile(device, channel, "/bluetooth/RSSI.csv") File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lightblue/_obex.py", line 257, in sendfile raise OBEXError("server denied the Put request") OBEXError: server denied the Put request

I already paired with other devices.Please told me how to write a code in a way you are saying. If you have some sample code then share it. Thanks..

Comment: @Kong Chun Ho 
My Script is:

    from lightblue import *  
    finddevices()
    services = findservices("54:27:58:DA:31:10")
    services
    D = [ (x,y,z) for x,y,z in services if "obex" in z.lower() and "push" in z.lower()]
    D
    (device, channel, description) = D[0]
    obex.sendfile(device, channel, "/bluetooth/RSSI.csv")

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible. (I am not an expert on Bluetooth, and am willing to be proved wrong BUT). [Simon Long states](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/)

> Bluetooth support is limited at this stage; you can pair with pretty
>   much anything, but you can only usefully connect to devices which
>   support either the Human Interface Device or Audio Sink services – in
>   other words, mice, keyboards and other UI devices, and speakers and
>   headsets.